# _pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow

Tags: python, linux, deep-learning, load, pytorch

I am new to Deep-Learning, and I try to recurrence the code in https://github.com/swamiviv/LSD-seg, which is used for image semantic segmentation, but a problem happened in Pytorch, I really need your help.

Thanks very much.

Here's the environment:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1
Python 3.6.4
Pytorch 0.4.0
```

The code is for downloading the pretrained model but my server can't visit googledrive, so I downloaded the model from other method and updated the model file to the server, and changed the related code, but it didn't work.

The original code:

```
import os.path as osp
import fcn
import torch
import torchvision

def VGG16(pretrained=False):
    model = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=False)
    if not pretrained:
        return model

    model_file = _get_vgg16_pretrained_model()
    state_dict = torch.load(model_file)
    model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    return model

def _get_vgg16_pretrained_model():
    return fcn.data.cached_download(url='http://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B9P1L--7Wd2vLTJZMXpIRkVVRFk',path=osp.expanduser('/home/sunyuze/LSD/data/vgg16_from_caffe.pth'),md5='aa75b158f4181e7f6230029eb96c1b13',)
```

After I downloaded the model file by other method and put it in the specific position, I modified the code:

```
import os.path as osp
import fcn
import torch
import torchvision

def VGG16(pretrained=False):
    model = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=False)
    if not pretrained:
        return model

    state_dict = torch.load('/home/sunyuze/LSD/data/vgg16_from_caffe.pth')
    model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    return model
```

The error alert is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 157, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 76, in main
    vgg16 = torchfcn.models.VGG16(pretrained=True)
  File "/home/sunyuze/LSD/code/torchfcn/models/vgg.py", line 17, in VGG16
    state_dict = torch.load('/home/sunyuze/LSD/data/vgg16_from_caffe.pth')
  File "/home/sunyuze/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 303, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
  File "/home/sunyuze/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 459, in _load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow
```

Comment: I have the same problems.